# Python Pathfinding Optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, path-finding

So the task is to find the safest path for the player within a given maze *r*, where the amount of encountered monsters is as low as possible.

Every maze is represented as an *n* by *n* array, where '.' represents a floor tile, '#' a wall tile and '@' a monster tile.

Start is at the upper left corner and exit at the bottom right corner. This is an example maze:

```
r = ["....@",
     "@##.#",
     ".##@#",
     ".@..#",
     "###@."]
```

Player can only move right and down.

I'm able to create a working algorithm, but it slows down significantly as the maze size increases (e.g. a 20 by 20 maze). I'd appreciate any kind of help with optimizing this algorithm:

```
def count(r):
    n = len(r)
    visited = [[False for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    paths = []
 
    def pathfind(i, j, path, monster_count):
        if i == n - 1 and j == n - 1:
            paths.append((path, monster_count))
            return
        
        visited[i][j] = True
 
        if i + 1 < n and not visited[i + 1][j] and r[i + 1][j] != '#':
            if r[i + 1][j] == '@':
                pathfind(i + 1, j, path + [(i + 1, j)], monster_count + 1)
 
            else:
                pathfind(i + 1, j, path + [(i + 1, j)], monster_count)
 
        if j + 1 < n and not visited[i][j + 1] and r[i][j + 1] != '#':
            if r[i][j + 1] == '@':
                pathfind(i, j + 1, path + [(i, j + 1)], monster_count + 1)
 
            else:
                pathfind(i, j + 1, path + [(i, j + 1)], monster_count)
 
        visited[i][j] = False
 
    if r[0][0] == '@':
        pathfind(0, 0, [(0, 0)], 1)
 
    elif r[0][0] == '#':
        return -1
    
    else:
        pathfind(0, 0, [(0, 0)], 0)

    if len(paths) == 0:
        return -1

    return paths
```

Comment: Hi. Have you heard of Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: @stef I don't think there is a good heuristic for that.

Comment: @btilly I don't understand your comment. This is literally a shortest-path problem, where the length of a path is the number of monsters on it. Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't require a heuristic.

Comment: @btilly Actually the algorithm you described in your answer sounds suspiciously similar to Dijkstra's.

Comment: @Stef Modifying Dijkstra to solve shortest path without a heuristic gives you "breadth first search". What I described isn't even as good as that because you revisit nodes when you find an improvement, rather than never looking at the bad answers in the first place..

Comment: @btilly I don't understand. Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't use heuristics. Are you sure you're not thinking of A* rather than Dijkstra's?

Comment: @Stef OOPS! Yeah, you're right. Can I blame senility?

Comment: @btilly I often confuse left and right, so I guess confusing A* and Dijkstra's is not that bad

Comment: @Stef I also confuse left and right. It appears to be a family trait. But I don't feel bad about it. I know someone whose family trait is to about once a month forget that glass doors are a thing and attempt to walk through one at a mall. That would be worse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're slow is that you're exploring paths going through `(i, j)`  every time you find a path to that spopt, regardless of whether some previous path got to there and figured out what can be done.

Instead of `visited`, construct 2 data structures.  `came_from` and `monsters`.  In `came_from` you record what path you found that gets here.  In `monsters` you record how many monsters there were on that path.  If you get to a spot with a `came_from` you only continue exploring if you got there with fewer `monsters` than it already had.

And now when you're done you'll be able to start at the bottom right corner and follow `came_from` back to the start like a cookie trail.

There are improvements on this idea, but this should still find a path in reasonable time even with a 200 by 200 maze.